# Render one web page, simultaneously to two or more different users via Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie in Rails. Let's  say, I have a webpage, which is navigated only by me. Now I want other users ( chosen by me )  to share the same view as navigated by me, simultaneously. Same as that when we share screens in TeamViewer . Is this possible in rails 3.2 or 4.x? Are there specific "gems" for it? I heard about Websockets. Is this relevant to my query? Please explain it in layman language. Any online source to learn it would do a great help.

Comment: If the answer is too broad, a brief introduction would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make *reactive* webpages you need (the equivalent of) WebSockets. This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub?view=asciicast) describes an implementation for Rails 3.2.

If you were on Rails 4 you could use [Websocket-Rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails). (Why did you start with Rails 3.2 anyway?)

If you are not bound to the Rails platform then I suggest you take a look at [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/main), a JavaScript stack that supports live page updates out-of-the-box.

Comment: I googled for learning Rails, and came across Michael Hartl's tutorial  for learning rails "http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2" . I started with rails 3.2 to have a solid start after revision with rails 4.0 in the same tutorial. Is learning Websocket-Rails  easy, or should I prefer to learn javascript for Meteor. Which is easy and fast to implement? Thanks for your help.